# Do my equals and hashcode must be implemented based on compareTo method?

Tags: java, hashcode

```
class Ngram implements Comparable<Ngram>{
    String name;
    int count;

    public Ngram(String name, int count){
       this.name = name;
       this.count = count;
    }

    ...

   @Override
   public int compareTo(Ngram other){
        return Integer.compare(this.count, other.count);
   }
}
```

My class only has the compareTo() method, which only uses the 'count' variable to compare. If I use Ngram as key of Map, does that mean only 'count' will be considered when inserting a new object to the map?
If I want to add equals() and hashcode() to the class, must I only use 'count' in the implementation for comparison?

My real question is, when deciding the key of Map, I want to use the combination of "name" and "count", but when sorting the elements in the map or in a list, I want to use 'count' only for sorting purpose. In such a case, it seems my equals and hash code methods have to use both 'name' and 'count' as comparison criteria, but for sorting, I only want to use 'count' in the compareTo method. How to achieve this dual purpose? Does this demand make sense?

Do I have to create two almost identical classes to achieve the goal? The only difference between the two classes is the implementation of hashcode, equals and compareTo(). Is that right?

Comment: What kind of Map? You *can't* use this class as written as a key in a TreeMap unless you provide a Comparator, in which case its behaviour is determined by the Comparator, or unless it is a HashMap, in which case your `compareTo()` method isn't called at all, only your missing `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods, which will therefore be inherited from `Object` and have nothing to do wih your `compareTo()` method either. And you can't sort the keys of a HashMap. Your question therefore doesn't make sense.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you want to use this class as a key for maps you need to implement equals() and hashcode(), it is not an option.

compareTo() is not used by the map at all. It's only purpose is to order elements, a map is unordered.

To use this class as a key you need to make sure that two equals objects considered have the same hashCode. Make sure that you use the same fields in the construction of your equality and of your hash code.

One last note about your class : This count variable is scaring me a bit. To use a class as a key for a map you need to be sure none of the fields that are taken into consideration to compute the hashCode can change. If you key's fields change between the moment you put it in your map and the moment you want to fetch it back then the hashCode will have changed which is a problem since a Map rely on the hashCode to internally find your value.

Comment: Yes. it implemented the Comparable interface.

Comment: @user697911 Not in the code you posted. So this isn't the real code?

Comment: So I can use "name" and 'count' (count is constant) to implement the hashcode and equals, but 'count' only for compareTo() method? My impression is that hashcode and equals have to be consistent with compareTo method. Isn't it?

Comment: @Bruno It *is* an option, if you accept the behaviour of `Object.equals()/hashCode()`, and `TreeMaps` are ordered.

Comment: not really, you may want two different object to be ranked at the same position, if my way of saying it makes sense x)

Comment: @EJP You are right, I assumed a HashMap.
About overriding Object.equals()/hashCode(), it can be an option, but I don't consider it good practice to leave it ignored.  Default implementations of equals() and hashCsode() compares memory adresses not field values of your object.

Comment: Then what does it mean by 'hashcode and equals compatible with compareTo() method' in Java doc?

Comment: if two objects are equal via equals method compareTo method must return “0″ for them. This is verified in your class. If ngram1.equals(ngram2) == true this mean that  both name and count are equals for both objects, hence if you call ngram1.compareTo(ngram2) it will return 0 because both object store the same value for their respective count

Answer (score 0):

You must implement a `hashCode/equals` if you are going to be putting objects in a Collection, like a List, Map, Set, etc. For example, Sets would need to know if an object exists; Lists would need to know how to invoke `contains()`; and of course HashMap collections would need to know how to hash.

There is no direct effect on sorting, as that is done by the `Comparable` and `Comparator` interfaces, but it is always a good idea to add the `hashCode/equals` implementations for Collection usage. Multiple libraries and IDE's provide auto-generation or quick implementation.

By the way the two should always be implemented together -- many resources on that.